# How to make macro work with all cells of column A?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

How to make macro work with all cells of column A? So that can paste into several cells at a time and the data is converted. I need this in order to be able to convert multiple data at once.

I have this macro:

```
Option Compare Text
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim v As Variant
    v = Split(Target, " ")
    If UBound(v) <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Right(Target, 1) <> "m" Then
        Target = v(1) & " " & v(0)
    End If
End Sub
```

This macro converts the data to **(any number)m** and **(any number)M** be on the right.

For example:

```
L3 280M
500m FMA
Nest 475m
340m Pr6
720M uT10
etc.
```

Convert to:

```
L3 280M
FMA 500m
Nest 475m
Pr6 340m
uT10 720M
etc.
```

Comment: add a loop to your macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be so?

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim oCell As Range
Dim v As Variant
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Target) < 1 Then Exit Sub
    For Each oCell In Target.Cells
        If oCell.Column = 1 Then
            v = Split(oCell.Text, " ")
            If UBound(v) = 1 Then
                If Right(v(1), 1) <> "m" Then
                    oCell.Value = v(1) & " " & v(0)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next oCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great! But if try to delete all the data in column A — click on column A (so that it is all selected) and press the "Delete" key on the keyboard, then Excel will temporarily freeze.

Comment: Of course it freezes! After all, the macro needs to check 1048576 empty cells, and this takes time. :-) Just add the first executable line to the procedure - `If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Target) < 1 Then Exit Sub`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works perfect! As far as I understand can also use:  `Set Target = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(1), Me.UsedRange)
If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`